# How to switch different enpoint for a soap client

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have code that use soap client.

```
using (webTest.TestSoapClient sc = new webPrint.TestSoapClient())
                                {
                                    sc.Print();
                                }
```

I have the following in web.config

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/webservice/test.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestSoap"
        contract="webTest.TestSoap" name="TestSoap" />      
    </client>
```

Now I want to add more endpoints to the web.config. like

```
      <endpoint address="http://example.com/webservice/test.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestSoap"
        contract="webTest.TestSoap" name="TestSoap1" /> 

      <endpoint address="http://123.com/webservice/test.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestSoap"
        contract="webTest.TestSoap" name="TestSoap2" />       
    </client>
```

Can I create the soap client in code using different endpoint like follows:

```
    using (webTest.TestSoapClient sc = new webPrint.TestSoapClient("TestSoap1"))
                                {
                                    sc.Print();
                                }

    using (webTest.TestSoapClient sc = new webPrint.TestSoapClient("TestSoap2"))
                                {
                                    sc.Print();
                                }

    using (webTest.TestSoapClient sc = new webPrint.TestSoapClient("TestSoap3"))
                                {
                                    sc.Print();
                                }
```

Is that feasible, and how can I do it?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to do all that _manually_ ?

Comment: The endpoint being called may changed due to adding server or removing server. So I think this way, is it have a better way to do this?